# How do I create a folder in internal storage?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mediarecorder

I want to create a folder for my app to put audio files into. I want it to be in the same location where the DCIM folder lives. So when I run the emulator and go to `Files` -> `Internal Storage`, I want to be able to see the folder here (similar to how Snapchat creates its folder here). Is this even possible? I tried doing the below but got an error.

*Code:*

```
var path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() // this is /storage/emulated/0

    
val testappDir = File(path?.absolutePath, "/testapp/")
testappDir.mkdirs() //mkdirs creates any missing parent directories, mkkdir does not
if (testappDir.createNewFile()) {
   println("File created: " + testappDir.name)
} else {
   println("File already exists.")
}
```

*Error:*

> java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

Comment: Your permissions might not be set up correctly. You need to ensure that you're having storage permissions in your AndroidManifest file. Also with android 6 and above you need to ask for runtime permissions.https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs(). It might fail. And does! Only call it if the dir does not exist yet.

Comment: Do not put audio files in the DCIM folder. Use Music folder instead.

Comment: Why are you talking about internal storage when you call getExternal.....

Comment: @blackapps I don't want to put audio files in DCIM. I want to create a folder on the same level as DCIM and put the audio files in there.

Comment: Ok. I see. Sorry. But that will not go on Android 10 anymore unless... And why didnt you adapt code around mkdirs()?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a path for an external storage with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

The Exception `java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted` means that you don't have the permissions to read or write the external storage.

You have to add the permission to the Android Manifest and the at Runtime you have to request the permission from the user. More information about this can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

When you want to read and write the App Internal Storage you can found more information here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific